# How long have you been going?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Guy 1 - I'm seeing a therapist.

Guy 2 - Okay.

Guy 1 - You seem surprised.

Guy 2 - No, I don't know. A little, maybe. **So how long have you been going?** / **So how long have you been seeing that therapist?**

Guy 1 - For a few weeks.

Would "So how long have you been going?" be perfectly natural in this context?

Comment: Yes, it's totally natural. The other possibility sounds like there have been other therapists, and Guy 2 is specifically asking about the current one

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be perfectly natural. The other phrase is natural too, but the context is apparent without re-iterating the fact that Guy 1 has been seeing a therapist.

The word 'that' in the second version might imply that Guy 2 is asking about how long Guy 1 has been seeing this therapist as opposed to another therapist or something - especially if any emphasis is used in the speech.